# Make custom TemplateMethodModels available in Freemarker for Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

I created several implementations of `freemarker.template.TemplateMethodModelEx` for my Freemarker templates in my Spring Boot 2 project. Currently, in order to use them in my views, I need to add them to the model (“hash” in Freemarker terms) in every WebMVC controller.

I’d like to have a way to make them available in every view of my project without having to extend the model in every controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeMarker has a feature to add top-level variables on the level of the `Configuration` singleton, via the `Configuration.setSharedVariable(String, Object)` API. Apparently, Spring `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory` exposes that under the property name "freemarkerVariables": https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.html#setFreemarkerVariables-java.util.Map-